# User can write function in Windows Application

Tags: c#

I need to develop C# application where a user can call some customized functions that have been developed by us, that have to be executed at run time.

For example, suppose I have developed a class which has the following methods:

- Sum(params int[] values )
- GreaterThan(int Value,int CompareValue).

Now I want to provide a User Interface to the user, where they can call these in nested manner. For example:

```
GreaterThan(Sum(1,5,6,8),15)
```

My application then will then parse this and execute the functions accordingly. How do I approach this?

Hope my requirement is clear and will get some solutions to this.

Comment: You want to say that user can type: GreaterThan(Sum(1,5,6,8),15) , press button and see results?

Comment: *my requirement*, you requirement is to write code for you, not to fix a problem with your code. Show the effort and code you tried, and if you hit a *specific* problem, then come ask the question, we will be glad to help out.

Comment: Is this a console application or you are using other GUI ? How the user will give input ? by typing or by clicking a button ?

Comment: Your _"requirement is clear"_ but you won't _"get some solutions"_ because your question is **too broad**.  Your question sort of reads as a set of requirements. Any code to show? What research have you done? These things will help us help you.  Good luck!   _[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)_

Comment: Yes Kat.  I want user can type such functions on my application.

Comment: Kat, I have just started this project and want to understand either there is any library or any specific technique on which I should look in. That will make my task easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NCalc mathematical expressions evaluator](http://ncalc.codeplex.com/), it can evaluate expressions, for example

```
Expression e = new Expression("2 + 3 * 5");
Debug.Assert(17 == e.Evaluate());
```

for your requirements, you may need to write your own functions, check below answer :
[How to add a new function to Ncalc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875348/how-to-add-a-new-function-to-ncalc)

Comment: Damith, Thanks for your sharing.

Comment: But my requirement is not for mathematical expressions, I need this for multiple type of function related to my business logic.

Comment: @Brijesh But your examples and original question related to mathematical calculations.